# Run Web Component Tester on HTTPs

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

We need to test a Polymer element in an HTTPS URL when we run `$ wct`, aka the [Web Component Tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester).

We're developing an element for screensharing, which requires a Chrome screensharing browser extension which only works on HTTPS.

We're aware that WCT uses [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) under the hood so I was wondering:

Is there any way to run `$ wct` and provide it with some self-signed SSL certificates so it runs the tests under HTTPS?